# List all software installed from particular component (non-free, contrib)

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Is there a way to list all `non-free` and `contrib` software installed in Debian via `apt`?

`/etc/apt/sources.list` is as follows

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main non-free contrib

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

I added `non-free` and `contrib` years ago because I needed a non-free driver for my video-card, which has now been replaced with a new one that doesn't require a non-free driver. I'd like to get rid of the non-free stuff, but I'm afraid I might have installed other non-free software over the years which I cannot afford to uninstall.

Comment: See also: [How do I list installed packages with source URI, distribution and section in Debian?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183644/2465)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- `dpkg-query -W -f='${Section}\t${Package}\n' | grep ^non-free`
- `aptitude search '~i ?section(non-free)'`

`Section` will be non-free/... for everything from the non-free path.

[Note] for gcc docs...

```
 This documentation is licensed under the terms of the GNU Free
 Documentation License, and contains invariant sections, so it can't be
 part of Debian main.
```

(I wondered about that too, but didn't bother checking until it was mentioned.)

Comment: Both yielded different results (http://pastebin.com/rAhYHTk8). The NVIDIA stuff is the driver, so dpkg seems right! Upvoted. I just wonder what gcc-doc is doing there.

Comment: The NVIDIA stuff was already removed, apt probably listed it because it kept the .deb or something. I just remembered one thing I have from non-free which wasn't listed: `dpkg -l | grep -i nonfree` results in `flashplugin-nonfree`. I wonder why that wasn't listed by aptitude and if it's actually listing everything from non-free.

Comment: Because it's in contrib :: debian/pool/contrib/f/flashplugin-nonfree (`Section: contrib/web`)

Comment: A one-liner for both sections is  `dpkg-query -W -f='${Section}\t${Package}\n' | sort | egrep ^contrib\|^non-free`

Comment: Regarding `dpkg-query -W -f='${Section}\t${Package}\n'`:  `Section` does not display the components.  (At least, it does not for me on Ubuntu 18.04.)  An example component might be `main`, `contrib`, or `non-free`.  Whereas sections are things like: `admin`, `gnome`, `utils`, or `x11`.

Comment: Regarding `aptitude search '~i ?section(non-free)'`:  I get output when I search for the sections `universe` or `multiverse`, but not when I search the section `main`.  This seems very wrong.  My system is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Update to my previous comment:  So it turns out that "section" has an ambiguous meaning, and the component "main" is implied by default, rather than being explicitly specified.  See https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-subsections

Answer (score 9):

There is a program called `VRMS` (a virtual Richard M. Stallman) which will report all the non-free software on your system in a short summary. Its in the repo's and you can install it via `apt` ;-)

Comment: It's worth mentioning `vrms` adds itself to `/etc/cron.monthly`. I was pleasantly surprised when I got a mail from virtual Stallman a month after the install.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar 'urge' a few years ago and could not determine that the orginal package information is kept on the system after downloading the package. I don't think this information is available to `dpkg`.

So what I ended up was setup a clean virtual machine, setup the appropriate `/etc/apt/sources.list` and installed the whole list generated by:

```
dpkg --get-selections | fgrep -v deinstall | cut -s -f 1
```

the packages that would not install (I only did download to save some time with `apt-get -d`).

You might be able to do a similar thing using `apt-get --root-directory=some_dir` after temporarily changing your `sources.list`, but I would not sure if that uses your current install database and just moves the package there. A VM for this kind of experimenting is much safer. I normally have a clean basic install of my current Linux as VM, so I only have to clone that (not that installing Linux on a VM takes that long).

Comment: Nice "solution". I currently don't have the disk space for it, but I imagine apt will first display the packages that weren't found (hence are non-free), correct?

Comment: @Alex Yes that is correct. That is kind of missing from the answer. But Ricky's approach is better unless the unlikely happened and a package actually moved over time from one repo to another (and you are not up-to-date or the package did not change version number).

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229436). Here the command line:

> ```
> FILTER=non-free TMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d) && {
>   dpkg -l | grep ^ii | cut -f 3 -d' ' | cut -f 1 -d : | sort | uniq > ${TMP_DIR}/pkg_installed.list
>   cat /var/lib/apt/lists/*_${FILTER}_*Packages | grep "^Package:"  | sort | uniq | cut -d' ' -f2 > ${TMP_DIR}/pkg_filtered.list
>   comm -12 ${TMP_DIR}/pkg_installed.list ${TMP_DIR}/pkg_filtered.list
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

id like to answer for the opposite task. suppose we have a package and we want
to know from which repo it can be  installed.

for example "gnumeric"

```
# export name="gnumeric" && grep "$name" -Ri /var/lib/apt/lists | grep "Package: $name$" | grep binary | grep "ubuntu.com"
/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: gnumeric


# grep "ubuntu.com" -Ri /etc/apt | grep "bionic universe"
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb  [ arch=amd64 ] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
```

that is the answer:

```
deb  [ arch=amd64 ] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
```